# inner tube to fit in a 26 X 1.5 bicycle tire

Tags: innertube

I have a tire 26 X 1.5 what size tube should I buy for it?  As yet I have not tried tubes because I don't know what size to buy.

Comment: Read what it says on the box.  The boxes are usually pretty good about stating what sizes they fit.  26 x 1.5 is a pretty common size.

Comment: (As to Schrader vs Presta valves, it would be rare for a standard bike with a 26 x 1.5 wheel to take a Presta valve.  Presta valves are usually only seen on fancier bikes.)

Answer (score 4):

A tube can usually fit a range of different tire sizes, because the tube can stretch a bit when it is being inflated.  The range of tire sizes is written on the package that you see at the store. Since your tire is 26"x1.5", you need to find a tube that is labelled as being appropriate for a 26" (diameter) tire and a width range that includes 1.5".

For example, look at this picture:
[image: tube_package]
Among other things, the label says 26x1.5/2.20. This means that it's intended for 26" tires where the width is between 1.5" and 2.2". So this one would work for you. I hope this helps in deciphering the labels if you go to a bike store.

A previous answer mentioned the two different kinds of valves; this is important. You just have to look at the valve on the old tube that you want to replace and figure out if it's Schrader or Presta.

Presta valves look like this: [image: presta]

And Schrader valves look like this: [image: schrader]

If you want to buy it online, here are two that would work:

- With a Schrader valve: [http://www.amazon.com/Avenir-Regular-Schrader-Valve-1-50-1-75/dp/B00165PA1W](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00165PA1W)
- With a Presta valve: [http://www.amazon.com/Diamondback-26x1-5-Threaded-Presta-Bicycle/dp/B00MJYP0KU](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MJYP0KU)

Answer (score 2):

It should say on the package at the store what the size is. If you have a 26 x 1.5in tire, you will just want to make sure the tube you buy overlaps the 1.5in. For example, it may say 26" x 1.5" to 2".

You will also want to make sure you get a tube with the proper kind of valve. Either Presta or Schrader. Look at the valve on tube you already have, if it looks the same as the valve on a car tire, it is a schrader. If it is all metal with a lot more threads on it, it is a presta.